# VBA to check which stylesheet is loaded in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I have a small macro to change styles automatically, but it won't work unless the right style sheet is selected. At the moment, it looks like this:

```
ActiveDocument.ApplyQuickStyleSet2 ("Anthology")

'change direct formatting to styles
Call DoReplaceStyle("Subtle Emphasis", True)
Call DoReplaceStyle("Bold", , True)

'etc
```

and it works just fine. But is there a way to just check which style set is loaded, instead of re-applying it every time?

```
'e.g.
If [current style set] <> "Anthology" Then
      ActiveDocument.ApplyQuickStyleSet2 ("Anthology")
End If
```

(Am I overthinking things? Yes. Does Word do weird and inexplicable things with styles sometimes? Also probably yes and aliens *X-files theme*)